# Specify Duration while creating Stripe Subscription Plan

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I'm using Stripe PHP SDK to create a subscription plan dynamically.

```
use \Stripe\Plan;

Plan::create(array(
  "amount" => 2000,
  "interval" => "month",
  "name" => "Amazing Gold Plan",
  "currency" => "usd",
  "id" => "gold")
);
```

I wanted to ask is there a way to mention/handle the duration of a plan. Like I wanted to make a subscription by the plan for a limited time suppose 3 months and after 3 months I wanted the plan to automatically get removed from the subscription. I don't want to cancel the whole subscription as in my case there could be multiple plans associated with a subscription. SO I simply want to remove/detach the plan from the subscription.

I had gone through the Stripe SDK docs to find this but to no avail.

Comment: I think you need to create price rather than plan

Comment: @ashokpoudel: I check the plan api but same issue here https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/create

Comment: I should also add that it's possible to manually handle an upgrade or downgrade scenario by managing the Price line items yourself via the API when the 3 month period elapses. You can do this by calling the API to change the Subscription line items. An example of upgrading or downgrading can be found here: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/upgrade-downgrade#changing

Answer (score 1):

A Subscription Schedule [1] will be what you require here to automate changes to the underlying Subscription using phases [2].

The use of a schedule will allow you to specify, for example, a monthly Price that will iterate for 3 months in the first phase. Then you can define in the next phase what will happen, for example change the Prices in some way, like adding or removing Prices. An example may look like this:

```
\Stripe\SubscriptionSchedule::create([
  'customer' => 'cus_xxx',
  'start_date' => 'now',
  'end_behavior' => 'release',
  'phases' => [
    [
      'items' => [
        [
          'price' => 'price_print', # Monthly Price
          'quantity' => 1,
        ],
      ],
      'iterations' => 3, # Iterates for 3 months
    ],
    [
      'items' => [
        [
          'price' => 'price_print',
          'quantity' => 1,
        ],
        [
          'price' => 'price_digital',  # An extra price
          'quantity' => 1,
        ],
      ],
      'iterations' => 1, # Iterate for 1 month
    ],
  ],
]);
```

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules#managing

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscription_schedules/object#subscription_schedule_object-phases

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to create price instead of plan and the code would be like this (Not sure I use different platform but you can try)

```
use \Stripe\Plan;

$price = \Stripe\Price::create([
    'product' => '{{PRODUCT_ID}}',
    'unit_amount' => 1000,
    'currency' => 'usd',
    'recurring' => [
     'interval' => 'month',
     'interval_count' => 2 //Try tweaking this value for change
    ],
]);
```